# On Item Click for List View

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an List view and a button in a Linear layout. I cannot extend ListActivity(to use Onlistitemclick) , but I have to select an Item in the list view which opens up another view , where I have to fill in the details from SQLite DB.

What is the best method to implement this for the following code assuming the database works ? I am a beginner. All suggestion related to the method and the code are welcome.

Thanks in advance,

```
public class Contacts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int NewContact_Request_Code = 1;
    Button newcontact;
    ListView listview;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Contacts";
    int mInt = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactview);
        // Set the content to contactview.xml

        // newcontact = NEW CONTACT button
        // listview = MyList List View
        newcontact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddcontact);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        // Make a New Database
        DBContact info = new DBContact(this);
        // Open , get Information from database and close it
        info.open();
        String[] data = info.queryAll();
        info.close();
        // listview = getListView();
        listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // Display the names
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Contacts.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
         listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        newcontact.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // @Override
    // protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    // {
    // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Intent viewintent = new Intent(Contacts.this, ViewContact.class);
    // String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    // viewintent.putExtra("name_clicked", item);
    // startActivity(viewintent);
    //
    // }



    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent newintent = new Intent(Contacts.this, AddNewContact.class);
        // start actiivity for result - to get the name of the new contact
        startActivityForResult(newintent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // pass the value of the string via cursor and update the list
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set **[OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)** to your `ListView` like below

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Do some more stuff here and launch new activity

  }
});
```

Comment: I am really sorry , i have been doing android from a few weeks before.Could you please explain??

Comment: @user1693503 What will i explain about. You want to know how to handle that one?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could.There is no point in copying and pasting the code.I am very new to programming and I do not have a software back ground too.
My list view is a list of names. When one of them is clicked, I want to pass that name parameter to another class. what is that in this ?? I know how to use intents and sending data with intents

Comment: @user1693503 Yes. Just do like this `String data = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()` in string data will provide which item you've selected. After getting this just pass this string to wherever you want. But, do this operation inside of `onItemClick`

Comment: @user1693503 You're welcome. Can you get the name from listview with my code?

Comment: I have few other errors in the code, I will rectify them and I will let you know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596639/emulator-freezing

See if you can help in this

Comment: @praveen can list item first or any one item automatic click .... can it happen..

Comment: @praveen ex for button automatic click we use button.performClick(); like this if any code for list item

Answer (score 2):

You can set an `onItemClickListener` on it explicity, like so:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

where `listener` is an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: I am really sorry , i have been doing android from a few weeks before.Could you please explain??

Comment: `ListView` has a number of 'items' (each row), and you want to know when any one item is clicked, rit? So you set a 'listener' on the `ListView` which will be informed whenever an item is clicked. Such a predefined listener class that can be used is `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. For an easy way to implement this, see SpK's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use `OnItemClickListener()` for list view no need to extend this activity from `ListActivity`

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {          

   }
});
```

Comment: I am really sorry , i have been doing android from a few weeks before.Could you please explain??

Comment: just use this code for list view onItemClick and then use intents to navigate to another class..

Answer (score 0):

```
private final ListView.OnItemClickListener ListClick = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // your action
    }
};
```

and set this way

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(ListClick);
```

Comment: I am really sorry , i have been doing android from a few weeks before.Could you please explain??

Comment: i think you've got your answer. You have a long way to go. Good luck.

Comment: Yes .ran into one more
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596639/emulator-freezing

see if can help on this one