# Secondary Activity goes the Main Activity before all the data can be input  

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have written an to view , edit and create contacts . When  I run the code in emulator , it allows me to type the name but I cannot switch to other Edit Text and the emulator freezes.Even if I switch, the only thing I can do is press back button after. here is my code , could you please help me in debugging. I am new to android programming , all suggestions are welcome.

```
public class AddNewContact extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button Save;
    EditText Newname, NewPersonalPhone, NewHomePhone, NewOfficePhone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newcontact);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveContact);
        Save.setOnClickListener(this);
        Newname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newname);
        Newname.setOnClickListener(this);
        NewPersonalPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newpersonalphone);
        NewPersonalPhone.setOnClickListener(this);
        NewHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newhomephone);
        NewHomePhone.setOnClickListener(this);
        NewOfficePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newofficephone);
        NewOfficePhone.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean didItWork = true;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String nname = Newname.getText().toString();
            String npphone = NewPersonalPhone.getText().toString();
            String nhphone = NewHomePhone.getText().toString();
            String nophone = NewOfficePhone.getText().toString();


            DBContact newentry = new DBContact(AddNewContact.this);
            newentry.open();
            newentry.newRow(nname, npphone, nhphone, nophone);
            newentry.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            didItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog display = new Dialog(this);
            display.setTitle("ERROR");
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText(error);
            display.setContentView(text);
            display.show();
        } finally {
            if (didItWork) {
                Dialog display = new Dialog(this);
                display.setTitle("CONTACT SAVED!");
                TextView text = new TextView(this);
                text.setText("Sucess");
                display.setContentView(text);
                display.show();
            //  startActivity(new Intent("CONTACTS.class"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

LOGCAT

```
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913): Activity com.example.contactlist.AddNewContact has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41236e28 that was originally added here
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.contactlist.AddNewContact has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41236e28 that was originally added here
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.example.contactlist.AddNewContact.onClick(AddNewContact.java:56)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:7669)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5382)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7086)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1358)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1892)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1369)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2356)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3575)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3531)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3113)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2930)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 02:58:35.518: E/WindowManager(1913):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert new Contact? Have you give the permission `WRITE_Contacts` in your manifest.xml file.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to write to a database which i have created . It gets stuck in between. .also when i restart it , the name is visible on the list view i have created

Comment: Just have a look at [this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-10.html) You will be able to learn lot of things.

Comment: that was really good link for whhat i am doing . thank you again

Comment: @SpK, it is still crashing . I have pasted the log cat please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need 
 `setOnClickListener()`

for even edittexts?

why are you trying to use `setOnClickListener()` on edittexts. Is there any special reason for this?

once try to remove them and just use `setOnClickListener()` for button and run the logic.
If you have any special reason for using `setOnClickListener()` for edittext explain it once